# Matrix Addition over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We're defining Matrix addition as $M(k,n) \times M(k,n) \rightarrow M(k,n)$. Can we add two matrices, A = $M(k,n)$ and $B = M(k,n)$ of the same size but over different fields? For example, A is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and B over $\mathbb{C}$? Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you make sense of addition in two different fields?  Because that's what you want to do, just in $kn$ independent slots.

Comment: Also, your example question isn't the best since $\mathbb{R}$ is naturally a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, so really you're just adding in $\mathbb{C}$.  You should ponder your question in something like $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Randall So how can I change my example where one is not a sub-field of the other? I noticed that you can add elements in $\mathbb{R}$ to elements in $\mathbb{C}$ because you are just adding real numbers and not changing the complex part.

Comment: Well in my view you cannot do this.  This violates all sorts of operational philosophies in algebra.  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The part where a field is not a sub-field of another field, or addition in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The first bit.  Certainly I believe in addition in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I mean, just experiment and try.  Try to make sense of a reasonable addition across $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$.  You'll see the problems pop up.

Comment: @Randall Thank you Professor, I appreciate the help!